# WP8 - Auto scrolling text in full textbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have looked around already for a solution to my issue, but couldn't find any.

I'd just need to know how to set a TextBox to make it able to "scroll" when it's full.

Basically, I don't need it to get completely empty when I insert 1 char (and that char inserted) but I need something like a FIFO Textbox.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AcceptReturn = true / TextWrapping = true

Comment: It was "TextWrapping = NoWrap", so basically "False", but thanks anyway, I got it figured out after your tip! :)